# Resize a Jtable Vertically based on it's content

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

I have a view in my java project that needs to resize a table.
I have **n** number of **Jtables** inside a **JScrollPane**. Some of them doesn't have enough rows to fill the total size of the table. The best solution I think would be to resize the table to fill to the number of rows that were allocated.

1) The table has a dimension of 4x4 but if there is not enough rows (i.e, less than 4) it will have a gap, which I don't want.

Since this table is static and won't be changed how can I resize this table programmatically based on the number of rows that it will have, like having 1, 2 or only 3 rows and not have this gap?

PS: I know how many rows it will have, I just don't know how to resize the table height programmatically during runtime.

[image: TableModel]

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: @ItamarGreen It is working but with the gap.

Comment: @ViníciusPachecoVieira what do you mean?

Comment: I guess I did not understand what you mean. If you mean by "found a solution" then no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this table is static and won't be changed how can I resize this table programmatically based on the number of rows that it will have,

After adding all the data to the table you can use:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

Then when the table is added to the scroll pane the size of the scroll pane will be the preferred size of the table.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `JTable` stretch to fit the height of the view, you can call:

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight-boolean-):

> Sets whether or not this table is always made large enough to fill the height of an enclosing viewport.

Comment: It only work if the table is too small, it doesn't help fitting if the table is too large and with too few rows.